# ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError:

Tags: julia

Dentro del siguiente codigo cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
numeros = readline(stdin)
respuesta = 0
for i in split(numeros)
#  print(i)
respuesta = parse(Int64, i) + respuesta
println(respuesta)
end
```

No se porque si la variable esta definida ¿por que pasa esto ?

Answer (score 1):

Se debe al [scoping de las variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/), que se implementó a partir de la versión 1.X (si mal no recuerdo).

Si te refieres a la sección "Local Scope" verás que si quieres usar una variable dentro del algún ciclo, tendrás que declararla dentro del ciclo. El ejemplo que ellos ponen en esa misma sección es este:

```
for i = 1:10
       z = i
   end

z
```

que arrojará el error "ERROR: UndefVarError: z not defined". Una posible alternativa es definir tu variable respuesta como una variable global.